# Struggling to position Boostrap with my own CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When trying to position my search bar at equal y level to the "Art Store" text, it does not do this.

```
   <div id="logoRow" >
            <h1>Art Store</h1>
            <form class="searchBar">
               <div class="input-group locationSearch">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
```

That is my text for the art store and then the search bar. My search bar looks like this with none of my own CSS:
[image]

When I add my own CSS, it looks like this

```
.searchBar {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

[image]
I want to position my search bar on the right side positioned at an equal y level to the Art Store text. When I use float: right, it positions the search bar down into the bottom navbar...?
[image]
This is not what I want to happen. I'm unsure why this is happening as it happens even when I set the position to relative. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is a little bit more code if that helps. (includes the bottom navbar)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Chapter5</title>
      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="assign3.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div id="topHeaderRow" >
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to Art Store, Login or Create a new Account</a>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav moveRight">
                     <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Wish List</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
         <!-- end topHeaderRow -->
         <div id="logoRow" >
            <h1>Art Store</h1>
            <form class="searchBar">
               <div class="input-group locationSearch">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
         <!-- end logoRow -->
         <div id="mainNavigationRow" >
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynavbar">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Art Works</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Specials
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Special 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Special 2</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
         </div>
         </nav>     
         </nav>
         </div>
```

Comment: incomplete code given

Answer (score 1):

I'am added a code into your case

```
#logoRow {
display:flex;
width:100%
}
#logoRow h1 {
  margin-top:0;
}
#logoRow form.searchBar {
  width:40%
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:auto;
 }
```

I'm used `margin-top:0px` for remove `margin` from bootstrap into `#logoRow` 
**So will get output like this**

```css
#logoRow {
display:flex;
width:100%
}
#logoRow h1 {
  margin-top:0;
}
#logoRow form.searchBar {
  width:40%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:auto;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chapter5</title>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="assign3.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="topHeaderRow">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to Art Store, Login or Create a new Account</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav moveRight">
            <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wish List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- end topHeaderRow -->
    <div id="logoRow">
      <h1>Art Store</h1>
      <form class="searchBar">
        <div class="input-group locationSearch">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end logoRow -->
    <div id="mainNavigationRow">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynavbar">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Art Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Specials
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Special 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Special 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Chapter5</title>
      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="assign3.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <style>
       .searchBar {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
             <div id="topHeaderRow" >
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to Art Store, Login or Create a new Account</a>
                      </div>
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav moveRight">
                         <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Wish List</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </div>
                </nav>
             </div>
             <!-- end topHeaderRow -->
             <div id="logoRow" >
                <h1>Art Store</h1>
                
             </div>
             <!-- end logoRow -->
             <div id="mainNavigationRow" >
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynavbar">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Art Works</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Specials
                         <span class="caret"></span></a>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Special 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Special 2</a></li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                   </ul>
                  <form class="searchBar">
                   <div class="input-group locationSearch">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </form>
                </nav>
             </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if i understand correctly you can use display flex to get your desired results. See the below css for how I solved it. [click here for a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFywr.png)

```
#logoRow{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

#logoRow h1{
   margin: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
.searchBar {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```